# Firebase cloud function error code and error message is always Internal on Android

Tags: java, android, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm developing a feature for my app, where one user can send a notification to another user using cloud functions. My functions and my notifications work as expected, but I'm not able to handle errors in a proper way, because I always get "INTERNAL" as the error on my Android code.

Here is my code for Android:

```
public static Task<String> callFirebaseFunction(HashMap<String, Object> data, String funcion){

    FirebaseFunctions mFunctions = FirebaseFunctions.getInstance();

    return mFunctions
        .getHttpsCallable(funcion)
        .call(data)
        .continueWith(new Continuation<HttpsCallableResult, String>() {
            @Override
            public String then(@NonNull Task<HttpsCallableResult> task) throws Exception {
                return (String) task.getResult().getData();
            }
        });
}
```

Here is where I call *callFirebaseFunction*

```
Utilities.callFirebaseFunction(dataNoty, nombreFuncion)
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<String> task) {
            if ( !task.isSuccessful() ){
                Exception e = task.getException();
                if (e instanceof FirebaseFunctionsException) {
                    FirebaseFunctionsException ffe = (FirebaseFunctionsException) e;
                    FirebaseFunctionsException.Code code = ffe.getCode(); // It's always INTERNAL
                    Object details = ffe.getMessage(); // It's always INTERNAL
                } else {
                    // handle error
                }
            } else {
                // success
            }
        }
    });
```

And here is my code for my cloud function

```
exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    let data     = req.body.data;
    let id = data['id'].toString();
    db.collection('users').doc(id).get()
        .then((snapshot) => {
            let infoUser = snapshot.data();
            // Verifies data
            if ( typeof infoUser !== "undefined" && Object.keys(infoUser).length > 0 ){
                // Some code
            } else {
                throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
                    'invalid-argument',             // code
                    'Error',                        // message
                    'User ' + id + ' not found'     // details
                );
            }
        }).then( () => {
            console.log('Success');
            return res.status(200).send("success");
        }).catch( error => {
            res.status(500).send(error.details);
            return new functions.https.HttpsError(error.code, error.details);
        });
});
```

I've tried different versions of code in my catch segment, for example:

```
.catch( error => {
    res.status(500).send('Error');
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError('invalid-argument', 'Error');
});
```

I don't know how am I supposed to make my catch segment, and I really need to get  the error I throw in node (not just "INTERNAL").

Comment: it sends out status-header `HTTP 500`, which is an `internal server error` ...maybe replace the `throw` with a `return new functions.https.HttpsError()`? the error code MUST be a integer... eg. `HTTP 400` or `HTTP 422`.

Comment: I've tried with return and same result. Error code must be a string, here is the documentation for HttpsError https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.https.HttpsError

Comment: indeed. however, those strings are for constants, which are mapped back to common HTTP error-codes: https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/master/google/rpc/code.proto ...the correct error-code would be `UNAUTHENTICATED`... this means `res.status(401)`. one can notify of the error by two different methods (one of them is enough, you always have both).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Callable functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) require the following format:

```
exports.yourFunction = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  // ...
});
```

It is not the same thing as an [HTTP triggered Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events), which is what you're using. You can still access it using an HTTP request from your Android app, but if you want to use `mFunctions.getHttpsCallable(function).call(data)`, you will need to use a Callable Cloud Function, which I linked above.